# SAS: ODS EXCEL (how to name different sheets)

Tags: sas, proc, ods, tabulate

I want to export a table generated by `PROC TABULATE`. My code goes like this:

```
ODS EXCEL FILE="myFile.xlsx" (options sheet_name="CRIME TYPE");

  PROC TABULATE DATA=myData;
    TITLE 'myTitle';
    BY crime_type;
    CLASS year;
    CLASS nation / ORDER=FREQ;
    TABLES year, nationality / CONDENSE;
  RUN;

ODS EXCEL CLOSE;
```

This creates me an excel file with different sheets:

```
THEFT     
      country1  country2 country3 ...
--------------------------------------
1990           
1991
1992
--------------------------------------



ASSAULT  
      country1  country2 country3 ...
--------------------------------------
1990           
1991
1992
--------------------------------------
```

Unfortunately, the sheets do not have the names of the different crimes (theft, assault, …) but are called "CRIME TYPE 1", "CRIME TYPE 2" and so forth (`SHEET_NAME="CRIME TYPE"`).

Does anyone know how to name the sheets according to the values of the variable `crime_type`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to name the sheets using values of `crime_type` variable, you can use `options(sheet_name='#byval1')` instead `(options sheet_name="CRIME TYPE")`

Answer (score 0):

try this solution from SAS support 
https://communities.sas.com/t5/ODS-and-Base-Reporting/ODS-Excelxp-PROC-TABULATE-multiple-sheets/td-p/359181